# Word for when someone asks if you remember them

Tags: single-word-requests

I don't know if it's common everywhere, but in my country any family-or-friends gathering has at least one person who will come up to you and ask if you remember them, as if they're cashing in on a coupon of shaming you publicly. And I was thinking so common an occurrence should have a word for it.

So . . . is there a word for it?